# How do I place connect a template to a certain content type

Tags: 8

As the questions says, how do I perform this and how do I render certain fields at certain spots placed in the template file?

I already got it so that everything is placed by using

> {{ page.content }}

But how do I do something like:

> {{ field_textblock }}

In where the given input in that field would be display on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the "without" filter on the {{ page.content }} as below:

```
{{ page.content|without(field_textblock) }}
```

and then you should be able to output "field_textblock" as you were before.

There is a good page about twig filters here https://www.drupal.org/node/2357633

Comment: I tried this put it doesn't seem to print anything. The current name of my template file is "page--node--11.html.twig". The name of my content type is template_test but I can't seem to connect this through my .theme file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct template for that.

The syntax changed from PHPTemplate to Twig but conceptually, everything is still pretty much the same as in Drupal 7.

Meaning, there are many, many nested templates and you need to find the right template to change what they display. The page template is just about displaying blocks/regions and the overall page wrappers.

If you want to change how a node with fields is displayed, you need to change the node template or even the field template for a given field.

To find out which template you need to overide, enable the twig debug mode. See `sites/example.settings.local.php` for instructions on how to enable "development mode" including twig debug, which will then display helpful markers around each template that tells you what template is used and what suggestions are available.